# Flipside Function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to Write a function in python which takes in a string `s` and returns a string
whose first half is the original string's second half and whose second half is the original string's first half.

Examples:

```
>>flipside('homework')

>>'workhome'

>>flipside('carpets')

>>'petscar'
```

*this all i was given i need help*

```
def flipside( s ):

    x = len(s)/2

    return _____________
```

Comment: Did you try slicing and adding?

Comment: Do you round up the half? or floor it? like carpets could be etscarp or petscar. after you have that, you can slice and add like @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need to get the first half and the second half of your string. That can be done with slices.

For example s[1:5] will return substring of s which begins at index 1 and ends before index 5.

s[:5] will return everything before index 5.

So, this code works as expected:

```
def flipside(s):

  x = len(s) / 2
  return s[x:] + s[:x]

print(flipside("homework"))
print(flipside("carpets"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out this is the solution it was simple I just wasn't getting it...

```
def flipside(s):  
     return s[len(s)/2:] + s[:len(s)/2]
```

Comment: There is no `x = len(s)/2` in your solution... you could use that to simplify the expression.

Comment: right i took out the x = lens(s)/2 you can use it to get the answer but i preferred to write it the way i did tho but thanks i really appreciated you input.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Floor Division "//"- The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.
That way you could get the positive number to slice your string.

```
def flipside(s):
    string_length = len(s)
    return s[string_length//2:] + s[:string_length//2]
```